# Sorting the linked list during insert

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, linked-list, insert

So I'm trying to insert nodes into linked list in descending order, but I struggle when I'm getting duplicate numbers and cant find a good solution for the problem. I either encounter missing numbers / program crash or program lists only 1 number infinite times.

Here is my code that I think works up to the "else" statement, it's the part that I cant figure out and im just leaving my last version, which doesnt work obviously

```
void Link::insert(int number) {
    Node *news = new Node;

    news->number = number;

    if(first == NULL) {
        first = news;
    }
    if(news->number > first->number) {
        Node *temp = first;
        first = news;
        news->next = temp;
    } else {
        Node *temp = first;
        while (temp->next || news->number < temp->number) {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = news;
        news->next = temp->next;
    }

}
```

If the other functions are needed or my main.cpp please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When you are first inserting, it goes into your first `if` condition and then sets `first=news`, but after that its again checking `news->number > first->number` which will be false, so going into the else condition unnecessarily. So either add `return;` in first `if` block or put others in `else` block.
keep track of previous element

```
else{
    Node *temp=first,*prev=null;
    while (temp && (temp->next || news->number < temp->number)){
        prev=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(prev==null){
       news->next=first;first=news;
     }
    else{
        prev->next=news;news->next=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved half of the problem apparently. It still doesnt sort it properly, for example when i type 1 3 2 5 it jusr prints 2 infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
    void Link::insert(int number){
Node *news = new Node;

news->number = number;

if(first == NULL){
    first = news;
    return;
}

for(Node *i=first, *pred=NULL;!i;i=i->next){
 if(i->number<number){
  if(i==first) {
   news->next=first;
   first=news;
  } else {
   pred->next=news;
   news->next=i;
  }
  break;
 }
 pred=i;
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm beginner in linked list and c++ so ive got almost no idea whats going on in your solution because of this if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should swap your 2 last lines, else you have  `news->next = news`, creating a cycle.

Anyway, I suggest to split the function in 2 (private) parts: One which found the `Node*` where to insert after (or `nullptr` for first position), and the method for the insertion (and it is so easier to debug).

```
Node* Link::upper_bound(int value) const
{
    if (first == nullptr || first->number <= value) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    Node* node = first;
    Node* next = first->next;

    while (next && value < next->number) {
        node = next;
        next = node->next;
    }
    return node; // we have: node->number < value && (next == nullptr || value <= next->number)
}

void Link::insert_after(Node* node, int value)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node(value);

    if (node == nullptr) {
        new_node->next = first;
        first = new_node;
    } else {
       new_node->next = node->next;
       node->next = new_node;
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
void Link::insert(int number) {
    insert_after(upper_bound(number), number);
}
```